# How to hide horizontal tabs on page load?

Tags: nodes, entities

I have installed the [field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module for horizontal tabs, so I can put several nodes in a tab via *rendered node*.

The question is simple:

How can I hide these tabs on page load?
I want to show the links but only when the user clicks on it, the tab shows up.

Thank you for your collaboration.

Gael

Comment: Would you be so kind and give me a link to your module? Are you using [field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this module, however, this sounds like something that can be solved by inserting javascript into your themes template and then adding an onclick function for the items/tabs you mentioned above. aka, they are always hidden, but when something is clicked on, they are shown.

Comment: @Huelfe yes my friend, i am using field group. the javascript that controls the tabs is in field_group/horizontal-tabs/horizontal-tabs.js    
unfortunately I do not have enough skill in tweaking jquery code, so thanks Janpan, I share your idea but I cannot put in practice, you know...

Comment: @Janpan will you be more tecnique?

Comment: Read [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1017838) how to use this module. This module provides hiding fields, if they are not in current tab. Either you have an javascript issue or you configured something wrong. Check your browser console if you get some errors.

Comment: @Huelfe if you have the solution write a comment, if you have tell me read the documentation only to gain some badge as good commentator, please keep it for you.

Comment: there is no option to hide nodes in the field group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Janpan suggestion, I have hidden the tab content and then added a click function, so I have shown the rendered node inside the div.

here the code:

```
 $("fieldset").hide();
                $(".tab a").click(function(){
                    $("fieldset").slideDown({
                        direction: "up"
                        }, 300);
                });
```